# What is the practical way to test for goodness-of-fit of alternative curves?

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, parameterization

I have fitted (that is, I have found the best parameters) two curves (Holling type III and Gomperz) to the data (red dots) and obtained the following regression:
[image]

How can I say which one is a better fit? (by eye, I would say Gomperz). How can I do -- preferably with R -- a test for the goodness of fit?

There are many tutorials online but I find them unclear. What is the best and simplest way?

Thank you

Comment: If the two models' parameters were fitted using standard lm  or nlme / lme4 non linear regression fonctions,  AIC or BIC of the resulting models will help you choose between the two regression models. The lower the better.

Comment: OK, so let's say I have these vectors: actual data (observed), expected by model 1, expected by model 2. Then I can apply let's say Chi square goodnes-of-fit and get two scalars based on the formula `sum(((expected-observed)^2)/observed)`. The two scalars are `holling = 3.780221`, `gompertz = 1.678961`. Since the latter is smaller than the former, the latter is a better fit than the former. If this is correct, is there a test I can apply to say "how smaller is smaller"?

Comment: I am afraid such a test does not exist. IMHO, in your context of choosing between two "good but conceptually wrong" models, the best model is simply the one with smallest AIC.

Comment: Fair enough, but is the chi square procedure correct?

Comment: Chi square goodness of fit is related specifically to categorical variables. don't use it for regression analysis. Please prefer AIC :-)

Comment: FYI, There is a version of AIC specifically tailored for small sample size, as your plot implies, called AICc. It includes a factor that prevents from selecting models with more parameters when sample size is small.